# Why histogram ticks showing different answers in gui in compare with non-gui?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, tkinter

I am using jupyter notebook and I want to draw histograms. When I do not use GUI it is okay and everything is shown correctly but when I use the Tkinter version of the code, all bars in histogram are shifted to left so the first bar is missing.(e.g: It should be 4 on a,3 on b,9 on c but it shows 3 on a,9 on b, where a,b and c are ticks)

this is the first code i do not use gui:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import*
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                               AutoMinorLocator)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
    select1=pd.DataFrame()
    select2=pd.DataFrame()

year1=1396
year2=1395

select1=df.loc[(df['yearj']==year1)]
select2=df.loc[(df['yearj']==year2)]
x=select1['monthj'].values.tolist()
y=select2['monthj'].values.tolist()
plt.xlabel('month')
plt.ylabel('number of orders')
bins=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

axx=plt.subplot()
axx.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
axx.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
plt.hist(y,bins,rwidth=0.8)
plt.hist(x,bins,rwidth=0.8, alpha=0.6)
```

and the output is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmskS.png)

and here is second code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                               AutoMinorLocator)
def compare_months(df,hh):

    compmon = tk.Toplevel(h


    bins=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

    select1=pd.DataFrame()
    select2=pd.DataFrame()
    year1=1396
    year2=1395

    select1=df.loc[(df['yearj']==year1)]
    select2=df.loc[(df['yearj']==year2)]
    xr=select1['monthj'].values.tolist()
    yr=select2['monthj'].values.tolist()
    xr.sort(key=int)
    yr.sort(key=int)


    f = Figure(figsize=(7,6), dpi=80)
    f.add_axes([0.15, 0.15,0.8,0.7])
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=compmon)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=4, column=5, rowspan=8)

    p = f.gca()    
    p.set_xlabel('month', fontsize = 10)
    p.set_ylabel('number of orders', fontsize = 10)
    p.hist(yr,bins,rwidth=0.8)
    p.hist(xr,bins,rwidth=0.8, alpha=0.6)
    p.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
    p.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))

but=Button(compmon, text="ok", command=compare_months(df,root))
but.grid(row=2,column=2)
```

and the output is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDoPI.png)

Why does this happen?

Comment: It looks like an index issue. You are only missing the 1st bar in the GUI image. Can you please provide your imports for both sets of code.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I edited the question. Now it has imports.